# By using multiple methods, find the perimeter of a triangle with given coordinates

Tags: java, math, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Perimeter {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter X1: ");
    double X1 = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter Y1: ");
    double Y1 = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter X2: ");
    double X2 = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter Y2: ");
    double Y2 = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter X3: ");
    double X3 = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter Y3: ");
    double Y3 = scan.nextDouble();

    finddistance(X1,Y1,X2,Y2,X3,Y3);
    double answer = triperimeter(base1, base2, base3);
    System.out.println(answer);

}

public static finddistance(double X1, double Y1, double X2, double Y2, double X3, double Y3){
    double base1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((X2 - X1),2) + Math.pow((Y2 - Y1),2));
    double base2 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((X3 - X1),2) + Math.pow((Y3 - Y1),2));
    double base3 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((X3 - X2),2) + Math.pow((Y3 - Y2),2));
}

public static double triperimeter(double base1, double base2, double base3){
    return (double) base1 + base2 + base3;
}
}
```

We are learning how to use multiple methods to write a code right now, the mistake I think I have are the following:

In method finddistance, I need to somehow share/return variables base123 with all the methods in this code, but i don't know how to do that.

And when I compile this code, it will give me just one error messege: invalid method declaration, return type required. On the public static finddistance line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try return an array of doubles

```
public static double [] finddistance(double X1, double Y1, double X2, double Y2, double X3, double Y3){
    double [] rv = new double [3];
    rv [0] = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((X2 - X1),2) + Math.pow((Y2 - Y1),2));
    rv [1] = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((X3 - X1),2) + Math.pow((Y3 - Y1),2));
    rv [2] = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((X3 - X2),2) + Math.pow((Y3 - Y2),2));
    return rv;
}
```

**edit**

and then change you calling to

```
double[] rv = finddistance(X1,Y1,X2,Y2,X3,Y3);
```

and then

```
double answer = triperimeter(rv[0], rv[1], rv[2]);
```

Comment: This still give the 3 errors cannot find symbol on line double answer = triperimeter(base1, base2, base3);

Comment: I have edited, maybe you can make that work.  I try not to give the whole answer as it is important for you to learn how to code by yourself

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that what your teacher wants is to have one `findDistance` method that calculates just one distance, but which you call three times.  Then when you've worked out the three lengths, you could add them all up in a separate method if you wanted to.

Note also that it's generally more accurate to use `Math.hypot` instead of `Math.sqrt` and `Math.pow` together.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter Ax: ");
    double ax = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter Ay: ");
    double ay = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter Bx: ");
    double bx = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter By: ");
    double by = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter Cx: ");
    double cx = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter Cy: ");
    double cy = scan.nextDouble();

    double lengthA = findDistance(bx, by, cx, cy);
    double lengthB = findDistance(ax, ay, cx, cy);
    double lengthC = findDistance(ax, ay, bx, by);

    double answer = perimeter(lengthA, lengthB, lengthC);
    System.out.println(answer);

}

public static double findDistance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2){
    return Math.hypot( x2 - x1, y2 - y1 ); 
}

public static double perimeter(double length1, double length2, double length3) {
    return length1 + length2 + length3;
}
```

Comment: thank you and i agree with what you said, and I like the code you wrote, but I gotta give it to wombat because he did it with the least change on my code

Comment: Cool.  I hope you learnt something useful from the wombat's technique

Answer (score 0):

The error is very explicit "return type required". You are missing a return type on method `finddistance`. You might need to revamp your code:

1. Return computed 'bases' in an  array of double
2. Pass each bases to the `triperimeter` method

Something like this:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Perimeter
    {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter X1: ");
            double X1 = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please enter Y1: ");
            double Y1 = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please enter X2: ");
            double X2 = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please enter Y2: ");
            double Y2 = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please enter X3: ");
            double X3 = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please enter Y3: ");
            double Y3 = scan.nextDouble();

            double bases[] = finddistance(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, X3, Y3);
            double answer = triperimeter(bases[0], bases[1], bases[2]);
            System.out.println(answer);

        }

        public static double[] finddistance(double X1, double Y1, double X2, double Y2, double X3, double Y3)
        {
            double base1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((X2 - X1), 2) + Math.pow((Y2 - Y1), 2));
            double base2 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((X3 - X1), 2) + Math.pow((Y3 - Y1), 2));
            double base3 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((X3 - X2), 2) + Math.pow((Y3 - Y2), 2));

            return new double[] { base1, base2, base3 };
        }

        public static double triperimeter(double base1, double base2, double base3)
        {
            return (double) base1 + base2 + base3;
        }
    }
```

You could also choose to make `base1`, `base2` and `base3` global static variable.

Comment: I tried that, now it give me errors saying cannot find symbol on line double answer = triperimeter(base1, base2, base3); one error on each of the varaible.

Comment: returning `void` when something needs to be returned doesn't sound like a good idea

Comment: @ScaryWombat I actually don't know that.

Answer (score 0):

These lines

`double base1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((X2 - X1),2) + Math.pow((Y2 - Y1),2));
 double base2 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((X3 - X1),2) + Math.pow((Y3 - Y1),2));
 double base3 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((X3 - X2),2) + Math.pow((Y3 - Y2),2));`

looks quite similar don't you think? Instead of calculation all three at the same time, try to reuse the function instead, because you might want to use it later as well but only on one base.

Comment: It does indeed. Because reusing the function would return all three bases if you call the function three times.

Comment: The problem is that the OP did not seem to know how to return values

Answer (score -1):

declare static variable

```
double base1=0; double base2=0; double double base3=0;
```

above main() & assign value in finddistance(); 
 Give return type as 'void' to finddistance()

Comment: Please don't get into the habit of using static variables instead of returning values from methods.  It will make your life much harder when you come to write more difficult programs.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem ur right its not good to use static coz it may produce memory leak.. but for simple code we can go for it..

Comment: *not good to use static coz it may produce memory leak* - What are you talking about ?

Comment: How on earth would you get a memory leak by using static variables?

Comment: in android studio it shows such warnings when i use static variables most of times. exactly not to variables but for views in android

Answer (score -2):

```
double answer = triperimeter(base1, base2, base3);
```

1) paramter is not defined , what is base1, base2? try to defined

2) `public static finddistance(double X1, double Y1, double X2, double Y2, double X3, double Y3)`

method declaration is incorrect method should have return type atleast void.

3) follow naming convention standard for method, class